# Slow reaction time of animate on $(window).scroll

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, scrolltop

Here is an [example](http://bramvanroy.be/webdevs/). When you scroll down, the nav bar gets animated. When you scroll back to the top it should be animated back. Unfortunately, this happens **very** slow. This has porbably to do with the fact that every you scroll, the coordinates have to be checked and calculated.

In other words, I am looking for a way to make this snippet more efficient:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var supra = $("div#supra-top-wrap"),
        topWrap = supra.children("div#top-wrap"),
        subNav = supra.children("nav#sub-nav");

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
        topWrap.animate({"top":"-38px"}, 400);
        subNav.animate({"top":"-70px"}, 400);
    }
    else {
        topWrap.animate({"top":"0"}, 400, function() {
            subNav.animate({"top":"0"}, 400);
        });
    }
});
```

Oh, and here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/FrcjR/) to get your way with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a simple case of animations being queued, so they execute only after previous animations are completed, so after about 400ms. Try adding stop(), like this:

```
topWrap.stop().animate(...)
subNav.stop().animate(...)
```

This should stop any running animations and start the new one right away.

Comment: Doing this fixed it for me, however it might be beneficial to use .stop(true) which includes the boolean to clear any current animation queues. See http://api.jquery.com/stop for more information.

Comment: I agree with James, it is a bit more bullet-proof to clear the queue with the true parameter, but if you use stop() on all animations there will never be a queue to clear, as it will never exist.

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed! Also, thank you for the comments, guys!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something else - This helps animation to react faster, but still not as effective as .stop() @EvidentAgenda mentioned.
I've compare the animation string and check whether it's the same or not / if not then we trigger the animation

```
var tt = {'top': 0}; // Animation string
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scroll > h) { var tt2 = {'top': 0}; }
  else { var tt2 = {'top': FHh*-1}; }
  //FHh is global var that is Div's height
  if(tt2 != tt) {
    $('#fixedHeader').stop().animate(tt2, 150);
    // can use together with .stop() - which even more faster
    tt = tt2;
  }
});
```